# PL/SQL - Using a conditional statement in the "where" clause to run between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, where-clause

Please excuse my very limited knowledge of PL/SQL.

I am attempting to use a conditional statement in the where clause.
I have a script which will run where run_date is between today and yesterday, however IF the day of the week is Monday, it should run where run_date is between today-3 and today-2.

I believe the issue is with the conditional statement I'm trying to apply, I was trying to use a CASE statement (example below) - but that only returns a single value, whereas I need to return a way of telling the script to run between two dates.

Code - 
(where I was trying to implement the case statement)

```
select record_type a, count(record_type) b
from orf_po_data
where
 (CASE 
   WHEN ((to_char(sysdate, 'D')) = '1') THEN (between trunc(sysdate-3) and trunc(sysdate-2))
   WHEN ((to_char(sysdate, 'D')) > '1' and (to_char(sysdate, 'D')) <= '5') THEN (between trunc(sysdate-1) and trunc(sysdate)
   ELSE null
END) run_date

group by record_type
order by record_type
```

Any assistance with this would be appreciated, if anyone needs more info, feel free to ask and I'll tell you what I know (although I have very limited experience with this kind of environment)

Thanks,

Comment: What is the time precision of the table column you need to filter by?  What is the name of thst column?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your `WHERE` condition with some boolean logics; if I understand well, you may need:

```
WHERE ( to_char(sysdate, 'D') = '1' AND
        run_date between sysdate-1 and sysdate
      )
      OR
      ( to_char(sysdate, 'D') != '1' AND
        run_date between sysdate-3 and sysdate -2
      )
```

What you wrote uses `CASE`, which is not a bad idea, but uses it as a statement, without giving a return value, instead than using it as an expression ( to compute a value) comparing its value with some other data.
However I prefer having my conditions as clear as possible, so I usually try to write them with boolean logic; this is of course my own point of view, without considering performance.

Please consider that I simply modified your conditions, assuming they are correct; for example you should consider truncatig values if you need to check your conditions based on days and not even hours, minutes, ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 Where datecolumn >= case ...... end -- start point
 And datecolumn < case ..... end -- end point
```

Divide tor case expression into 2 parts and compare the data to those calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN case_a THEN filter_a
     WHEN case_b THEN filter_b
                 ELSE exclude_the_row END
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
WHERE ( case_a AND filter_a )
OR    ( NOT case_a AND case_b AND filter_b )
```

Since your conditions for `case_a` and `case_b` (`to_char(sysdate, 'D') = '1'` and `to_char(sysdate, 'D') > '1'`) are mutually exclusive then you can ignore the `NOT case_a` part and the logic is:

```
WHERE (    TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') = '1'
       AND run_date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-3) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE-2) )
OR    (    TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') > '1' AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') <= '5'
       AND run_date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) )
```

You need to be aware that the `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameter will affect whether Monday is the first day of the week (in some territories it is not) and if you are going to be affected by this then you could get the numeric value for the day of the week (independent of the territory) using:

```
1 + TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )
```

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, you want to have a single condition on your date column (especially if there's an index the optimiser can use) comparing against values that can be evaluated statically at runtime. I would use something like this:

```
where datecolumn
  between trunc(sysdate) - case when to_char(sysdate, 'D') = '1' then 3 else 1 end
      and trunc(sysdate) - case when to_char(sysdate, 'D') = '1' then 2 else 0 end
```

Note also MT0's comments regarding `nls_territory` when determining the day of the week.

Comment: I like the simplicity but there is the small issue is that the second case was `to_char(sysdate, 'D') > '1' and (to_char(sysdate, 'D') <= '5'` rather than just `to_char(sysdate, 'D') <> '1'`

Comment: A possible fix is `CASE WHEN to_char(SYSDATE,'D')='1' THEN 3 WHEN to_char(SYSDATE,'D') > '1' AND to_char(SYSDATE,'D') <= '5' THEN 1 END` - if it doesn't match either case then the it will return `NULL` and `DATE - NULL = NULL` so the `WHERE` clause will fail to match and exclude the row.